# Clearing RDD data that is persisted on Spark node

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

In case of task failures,does spark clear the persisted RDD (StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER) and recompute them again when the task is attempted to start from beginning. Or will the cached RDD be appended.

I am seeing duplicate records in case of any task failures for a persisted RDD. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally , Spark will recompute the RDD if the cached RDD is not present in memory because of task failiures. You can check if this is happening, by checking your DAG or putting an accumulator in the stages before , if the RDD is computed by reprocessing the DAG, the counter will be 2x otherwise it will be x.

Comment: can you please elaborate the problem  "I am seeing duplicate records in case of any task failures for a persisted RDD" ??

Answer (score 0):

Task is the smallest individual unit of execution that is launched to compute a RDD partition.
In case a task fails run method notifies TaskContextImpl that the task has failed.Run requests MemoryStore to release unroll memory for this task (for both ON_HEAP and OFF_HEAP memory modes) and ContextCleaner is a Spark service that is responsible for application-wide cleanup of shuffles, RDDs, broadcasts, accumulators and checkpointed RDDs

As we know RDD is Resilient, i.e. fault-tolerant with the help of RDD lineage graph and so able to recompute missing or damaged partitions due to node failures.

Caching computes and materializes an RDD in memory while keeping track of its lineage (dependencies).Since caching remembers an RDD’s lineage, Spark can recompute loss partitions in the event of node failures. Lastly, an RDD that is cached lives within the context of the running application, and once the application terminates, cached RDDs are deleted as well.
Spark’s cache is fault-tolerant – if any partition of an RDD is lost, it will automatically be recomputed using the transformations that originally created it.

If RDD persisted in memory then on task fail executor JVM process fails too, so the memory is released.
If RDD persisted on disk then on task fail Spark shutdown hook just wipes temp files

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
rdd.unpersist()
```

to clear the cached rdd.